# Did a man sue himself and win?

Tags: law, lawsuits

According to this [article](http://www.scmp.com/article/169389/man-sues-himself-and-wins) and this [post](https://plus.google.com/+LarsFosdal/posts/bBmU5ZihJiV) a man hit himself with a boomerang and then proceeded to sue himself.

> A Kentucky man who threw a boomerang that flew back and hit him on the head has sued himself for US$300,000 (HK$2.32 million) - and won.
>
> And astonishingly, it will not cost him a cent because all the money he won comes from his insurance company.

Is this true, or has there ever been a case where somebody has successfully sued themselves, won, and gotten their insurance company to pay for it?

Comment: On the more general question of 'do people sue themselves?', yes, they do. For a few relevant cases (and humorous commentary), I refer you to Lowering the Bar's 'autolitigation' tag: http://www.loweringthebar.net/autolitigation/

Comment: Related: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/has-anyone-ever-won-a-lawsuit-against-himself on Law SE

Comment: @MrTheWalrus: More specifically, [this woman sued herself and won](http://www.loweringthebar.net/2015/02/utah-court-says-woman-can-sue-herself.html), with her insurance company picking up the tab.  (NB: I am not the Kevin who writes that blog)

Comment: If someone is being sued by themselves, how could they lose?

Comment: Here's a fresh link to [Lowering the Bar's autolitigation category](http://loweringthebar.net/category/autolitigation).  The one by MrTheWalrus in the first comment is dead.

Answer (score 3):

As per "[What Goes Around, Litigates Around](http://www.snopes.com/goes-around-litigates-around/)", Snopes.com, it seems to be fake.

> The "What the 'F' Facts" post renewed interest in the story of Larry
>   Rutman, which is nothing more than a fictional tale that has been
>   floating around the online world since it was first published in the
>   Weekly World News back in 1996